# Clipper: Split polygon layer with line layer - generates empty layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, clip

I am using QGIS 2.14.3 Essen.

I wanted to split several polygons with several lines. Both layer are in GK4 coordinate system (used layers generated by: QGIS right-click on layer -> Save as... ) and they optically intersect. But when I use the clipper function to split the polygons by the line layer, I get an empty layer. Why?? Is there any possibility to get log data of the tool? Using the clipper function the other way round, works (getting the lines inside of polygon).

[image: polygon and line layer]

You can download my data here:
https://kommsafe.de/#/public/shares-downloads/Ek2uYFrP9Yo9DFiHPPSGi9WFVhbvMj4J

Comment: In QGIS 2.18, there is the SAGA tool **Polygon-line intersection** which should do the job. Not sure if this is available in 2.14 though :)

Comment: That worked for me with this tool, thanks. Problem was probably: My line layer is divided in too many short segments, so that many polygons couldnt be cut completely. SAGA tool just generated starts of cut from plate edge on each polygon.